# Avoiding Multiple Function Calls?

Tags: java, function

I cannot figure out how to make it so it only calls `check4` once... this was for a homework assignment last semester and I got 5 points off for calling it multiple times but I would <s>not</s> like to know how to do it (the professor never said how).

I tried moving the check4 to after the if block but it really needs to go in between the last else if and the else which is not possible. The ONLY way the number should print is if all of the steps do not print out a word instead.

```
public class CheeseCakeFactory_ajh187 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int counter = 0;
        int printNumber = 0; //number that will get changed to one of the terms

        while (counter != 15 & printNumber < 210) { //as long as the counter is not 15 and print number is lesss than 210 it will keep looping.
            printNumber++;

            if (printNumber % 3 ==0 && printNumber % 5 == 0 && printNumber % 7 == 0) {
                System.out.print("cheesecakefactory");
            }
            else if (printNumber % 3 == 0 && printNumber % 5 == 0){
                System.out.print("cheesecake");
                check4(printNumber);
            }
            else if (printNumber % 3 == 0 && printNumber % 7 == 0){
                System.out.print("cheesefactory");
                check4(printNumber);
            }
            else if (printNumber % 5 == 0 && printNumber % 7 == 0){
                System.out.print("factorycake");
                check4(printNumber);
            }
            else if (printNumber % 3 == 0){
                System.out.print("cheese");
                check4(printNumber);
            }
            else if (printNumber % 5 ==0){
                System.out.print("cake");
                check4(printNumber);
            }
            else if (printNumber % 7 ==0){
                System.out.print("factory");
                check4(printNumber);
            }
            else { //if the number is not divisible by any of the other numbers we still have to check for the 4
                if (Integer.toString(printNumber).contains("4")) {
                    System.out.print("hoho");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(printNumber); //if its not divisible by 4, we just print the number
                }
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
            counter++;
            if (counter == 15) { //once the counter is 15 we need to put the new items on a new line
                System.out.print("\n");
                counter = 0; //resets the counter so that we can accomplish this every 15 passes.
            }
        }
    }

    public static void check4(int printNumber) {
        if (Integer.toString(printNumber).contains("4")) {
            System.out.print("hoho");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There are many ways that could be done, but you need to paste the relevant code here (not with an off-site link).

Comment: These are all else clauses? So check4 will always only be called once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would update `check4` to `return` a `boolean` (which you can save). Something like,

```
public static boolean check4(int printNumber) {
    return String.valueOf(printNumber).contains("4");
}
```

Then you can also save your tests into `boolean` variables. Something like

```
boolean mod3 = printNumber % 3 == 0;
boolean mod5 = printNumber % 5 == 0;
boolean mod7 = printNumber % 7 == 0;
if (mod3 || mod5 || mod7) {
    if (mod3 && mod5 && mod7) {
        System.out.print("cheesecakefactory");
    } else {
        boolean isCheck4 = check4(printNumber); // <-- call it once
        if (mod3 && mod5) {
            System.out.print("cheesecake");
        } else if (mod3 && mod7) {
            System.out.print("cheesefactory");
        } else if (mod5 && mod7) {
            System.out.print("factorycake");
        } else if (mod3) {
            System.out.print("cheese");
        } else if (mod5) {
            System.out.print("cake");
        } else if (mod7) {
            System.out.print("factory");
        } else {
            if (!isCheck4) { // <-- it doesn't have a 4, print it.
                System.out.print(printNumber);
            }
        }
        if (isCheck4) {
            System.out.print("hoho"); // <-- it does have a 4.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is beautiful. Thank you so much

Comment: How is this an improvement?  I prefer the original version to this.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your problem right so:
you create a global boolean variable named say isMethodCalled witch is false, then in the check4 method you make it true, and simple check if the isMethodCalled is false before calling the method.

```
boolean isMethodCalled = false;

if(!isMethodCalled) {
   check4() // do wathever you need to do to call check4()
}



public static void check4(int printNumber) {
    if (Integer.toString(printNumber).contains("4")){

        System.out.print("hoho");
    }

    isMethodCalled = true;


}
```

Comment: well the professor thinks that i referenced the function too much. she stated i dont have to have check4 in every else if.. and thats the problem. However, it works as it is currently written as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a flag, set it to `true` initially.

Then, wherever you dont want the check4 to run, set it to `false`.

after the if-else, check if the `flag` is`true`. if it is, execute 'check4(printNumber)'

```
public class CheeseCakeFactory_ajh187 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int counter = 0;
    int printNumber = 0; //number that will get changed to one of the terms
    int flag=true;

    while (counter != 15 & printNumber < 210) { //as long as the counter is not 15 and print number is lesss than 210 it will keep looping.
        printNumber++;

        if (printNumber % 3 ==0 && printNumber % 5 == 0 && printNumber % 7 == 0) {
            System.out.print("cheesecakefactory");
    flag=false;
        }
        else if (printNumber % 3 == 0 && printNumber % 5 == 0){
            System.out.print("cheesecake");
        }
        else if (printNumber % 3 == 0 && printNumber % 7 == 0){
            System.out.print("cheesefactory");
        }
        else if (printNumber % 5 == 0 && printNumber % 7 == 0){
            System.out.print("factorycake");
        }
        else if (printNumber % 3 == 0){
            System.out.print("cheese");
        }
        else if (printNumber % 5 ==0){
            System.out.print("cake");
        }
        else if (printNumber % 7 ==0){
            System.out.print("factory");
        }
        else { //if the number is not divisible by any of the other numbers we still have to check for the 4
            if (Integer.toString(printNumber).contains("4")) {
                System.out.print("hoho");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(printNumber); //if its not divisible by 4, we just print the number
            }
    flag=false;
        }

    if(flag)
    check4(printNumber);
        System.out.print(" ");
        counter++;
        if (counter == 15) { //once the counter is 15 we need to put the new items on a new line
            System.out.print("\n");
            counter = 0; //resets the counter so that we can accomplish this every 15 passes.
        }
    }
}

public static void check4(int printNumber) {
    if (Integer.toString(printNumber).contains("4")) {
        System.out.print("hoho");
    }
}

}
```